# Why is my react state not changing properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate using firebase in react. 
This is the component that tracks my authentification state.

```
    import { useState} from "react";


    function useAuth(fbAuth) {
       const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
       const createEmailUser = (email, password) => fbAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
       const signInEmailUser  = (email, password) => fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
       const signOut = fbAuth.signOut();

       fbAuth.onAuthStateChanged(async user=> {
          if (user) {
             await setIsAuthenticated(true);
             console.log(isAuthenticated, "should be true")
             return
          } else {
             await setIsAuthenticated(false);
             console.log(isAuthenticated, "should be false")
             return
          }

        });

       return {isAuthenticated, createEmailUser, signInEmailUser, signOut};

    }

    export default useAuth
```

The console logs when I click log in are

2useAuth.js:13 false "should be true"

2useAuth.js:17 false "should be false"

2useAuth.js:17 true "should be false"

4useAuth.js:17 false "should be false"

Answer (score 0):

The `setIsAuthenticated` function does not return a promise, so using `await` here doesn't really do anything. On top of that, the value of `isAuthenticated` is never modified (calling `setIsAuthenticated` doesn't change the value of the variable you already set at the beginning of the hook). Basically, doing a `console.log` within your `onAuthStateChanged` function doesn't make sense and won't do what you expect. If you want to get a better feel for what is happening, try putting a `console.log` at the beginning of the function, and just print the fact that you expect it to change. So something like this:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useAuth(fbAuth) {
   const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
   const createEmailUser = (email, password) => fbAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
   const signInEmailUser  = (email, password) => fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
   const signOut = fbAuth.signOut();

   console.log('isAuthenticated', isAuthenticated)
   //I'm assuming you only need to register the fbAuth.onAuthStateChanged
   //callback once. So We use useEffect with an empty array to have it
   //only run the first time this is rendered.
   useEffect(() => {
       fbAuth.onAuthStateChanged(async user=> {
          if (user) {
             setIsAuthenticated(true);
             console.log('isAuthenticated should be true after this')
          } else {
             setIsAuthenticated(false);
             console.log('isAuthenticated should be false after this')
          }
        });
    }, [])

    return {isAuthenticated, createEmailUser, signInEmailUser, signOut};

}

export default useAuth
```

You would then expect

```
//Initial render
isAuthenticated false

//Click log-in
isAuthenticated should be true after this
isAuthenticated true

//Click log-out
isAuthenticated should be false after this
isAuthenticated false
```

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong here. You are the getting the value before it is changed. To access the newest state you can use the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.
Also you have not asked anything like what is your issue and what do u expect?

Comment: I want to use isAuthenticated for protected routes. If isAuthenticated is true users should be allowed in, if not then rerouted back to landing page. The core problem is that isAuthenticated is not updating and even after clicking sign in, I get rerouted to the landing page.

Comment: @Rauno From what I understood, what about having an object, who is looking for the `isAuthenticated`  - something like the fakeAuth, which I found in [react-router] https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow Another way, which I have used in the past is using redux and passing it as props in different components but I don't think here it would be neccessary